# reading string inside quotes in perl

Tags: regex, perl

This is the string:

```
[quote="test post1"]this is a test post[/quote]
```

I want to retrieve only test post1 value

This is what I am doing...

```
[tmp test][item-param body] [/tmp]
$str1 = $Scratch->{test};
$str1 =~ m/"(.?)"/;
```

But it's not giving is the expected value: test post1

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you use ? in a regular expression it means "zero or one match". You probably meant * ("zero or more"), or + ("one or more").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;

my $str = '[quote="test post1"]this is a test post[/quote]';

if($str=~m/\"(.+)\"/) {
print $1;
}
```